# Multiple lines of output are repeating with wrong data

Tags: sql, oracle, operators

I'm trying to do a Select Statement in Oracle using the Operator `LIKE %` and for some reason the lines of output are taking on zipcodes of different people. Here is my code:

```
Select Distinct a.empno,a.ename,a.sal,a.job,b.empadr,b.empstate,b.empzip
From EMP a, EMPADDRESS b
Where a.empno = b.empno
And b.empzip Like '1%'
Or b.empzip Like '8%'
```

I tried adding brackets around the `AND` and `OR` but that didn't seem to work. I'm assuming it has something to do with how I wrote the columns in the first line but I'm not sure. If that is the case can someone explain why that happens, I would hate to have this problem again. Thanks in advance to all that answer.

Comment: Will you please give an example of the output your getting?

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to post output here.  My question was answered but if you would like me to post my old (bad) results here for future viewers I can do that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brackets are missing:

```
Select Distinct a.empno,a.ename,a.sal,a.job,b.empadr,b.empstate,b.empzip 
  From EMP a, EMPADDRESS b
 Where a.empno = b.empno
   And (b.empzip Like '1%' Or b.empzip Like '8%');
```

or you could use the JOIN syntax

```
SELECT Distinct empno,a.ename,a.sal,a.job,b.empadr,b.empstate,b.empzip 
  FROM emp a JOIN empaddress b USING (empno)
 WHERE b.empzip Like '1%' Or b.empzip Like '8%';
```

Comment: Looks like I added the brackets in the wrong area (before the AND instead of right after it).  I keep seeing people use the JOIN syntax so I think I'll do some research on whats the benefits of using it.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: It's just a little bit easier to read as it separates the filter conditions (empzip like ...) from the join conditions (a.empno=b.empno).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, objective is to return employee details based on zipcodes beginning with a "1" or an "8"?  When you mentioned applying brackets, was it like the following, which should work?

```
SELECT Distinct a.empno,a.ename,a.sal,a.job,b.empadr,b.empstate,b.empzip
FROM EMP a, EMPADDRESS b
WHERE a.empno = b.empno
AND (b.empzip Like '1%' OR b.empzip Like '8%');
```

Comment: Yeah I inserted the brackets before the AND (still learning SQL lol), thanks for your timely response though.

Comment: You're welcome and glad to help.  Learning SQL is an ongoing goal of mine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason your having trouble is cause of the OR. what it really is doing is a.empno = b.empno And b.empzip Like '1%' or if b.empzip Like '8%' is true, but you really want. a.empno = b.empno and (b.empzip Like '1%' Or b.empzip Like '8%') so you only check the zip codes, if the empno match. The other way it'll join random employees together and then check if their zip code matches.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to use "OR" in where clause, as a result the query can be very slow.
in your case you could use something like the following:

```
Where a.empno = b.empno
And substr(b.empzip, 1, 1) in ('1', '8')
```

Comment: Okay I'll practice with this for a bit, thanks for the advice.